# Error when using .between() for checking a long/lat location pulling it from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, location

I'm scanning through a data frame which is grouped by a specific id and am trying to return a locations surface type depending on certain long/lat locations which I have in a dictionary. The problem with the data set is that it's created at 100 frames per second so I am trying to find the median value as values before and after this point are incorrect.

I am using pandas jupyter notebook and have

This is the function which i want to pull the locations from the dictionary. The location is just a made up example

```
pitch_boundaries = {
    'Astro': {'max_long': -6.123456, 'min_long': -6.123456, 
'max_lat': 53.123456, 'min_lat': 53.123456},
}


def get_loc_name(loc_df, pitch_boundaries):

for pitch_name, coord_limits in pitch_boundaries.items():
    between_long_limits = loc_df['longitude'].median().between(coord_limits['min_long'], coord_limits['max_long'])
    between_lat_limits = loc_df['latitude'].median().between(coord_limits['min_lat'], coord_limits['max_lat'])
    if between_long_limits.any() and between_lat_limits.any():
        return pitch_name
# If we get here then there is no pitch.
```

call it here

```
def makeAverageDataFrame(df):
    pitchBounds = get_loc_name(df, pitch_boundaries)
     i = len(df_average.index)
     df_average.loc[i] = [pitchBounds]
```

finally where the errors occurs

```
for region, df_region in df_Will.groupby('session_id'):
    makeAverageDataFrame(df_region)
```

Actual results
`# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'between'`
or if I remove `.median()`: `None`

What I want is a new dataframe with something like

```
|surface|

|Astro|

|Grass|

|Astro|
```

Answer (score 0):

`loc_df['longitude']` is a series, and `loc_df['longitude'].median()` gives you a float, which does not have `between` method. Try `loc_df[['longitude']]`.

```
def get_loc_name(loc_df, pitch_boundaries):
    for pitch_name, coord_limits in pitch_boundaries.items():
        between_long_limits = loc_df[['longitude']].median().between(coord_limits['min_long'], coord_limits['max_long'])
        between_lat_limits = loc_df[['latitude']].median().between(coord_limits['min_lat'], coord_limits['max_lat'])
        if between_long_limits.any() and between_lat_limits.any():
            return pitch_name
```

And your problem with returning `None` is that your `makeAverageDataFrame` does not return anything (`None`). Try:

```
def makeAverageDataFrame(df):
    pitchBounds = get_loc_name(df, pitch_boundaries)
    return pitchBounds
```

Comment: Thank you very much that seems to be resolving the float problem and there is no error when I run it however there is still none returning when I run it so I think it may not be pulling from the dictionary but am unsure. The way the function is made I don't need that 'return pitchBounds' I will show above. If you could see anything wrong with above it would be greatly appreciated